# Why I not  able access my Site(SharePoint) , however I able to Access My SharePoint 2010 central administrator?

Tags: central-administration, licensing

[image]

Following is my log details

Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.SetupLicensingException: There is no known SharePoint Server Product installed.    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.SetupLicensing.get_InstalledOfficeServersProduct()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.SearchHelper.get_IsSearchSKU()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.SearchBoxEx.OnPreRender(Object sender, EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveIn... 126249db-3bcb-4bf0-a195-a7d32f79e44e
06/11/2011 15:59:46.25* w3wp.exe (0x0280)                           0x1070  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  ...ternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)   126249db-3bcb-4bf0-a195-a7d32f79e44e
06/11/2011 15:59:46.25  w3wp.exe (0x0280)

Please help me to over come this problem. My server I just reinstalled my  MS office and it Licensed version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has this solution been migrated from Windows SharePoint Services or other MOSS 2007 SKU? It looks like the exception hints that there is some sort of SKU/License issue

Comment: Last time when i used Every thing was working fine what i did just format my D: Drive in because my system running out of space in C: drive. (Drive D I installed office 2007) My C drive I installed office 2010 Trial version. So i did remove some register keys of office 2007. It may be the issue

Comment: I deleted all my site collection and recreate all site. I am facing the same error. Now What I did i try to open the site in SharePoint Designer I able to open the Site in SharePoint Designer. 1. http://home/_layouts/settings.aspx  but when i try to open the this(http://home/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx) link i am geeting the same error logs -------------------------------------Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.SetupLicensingException: There is no known SharePoint Server Product installed.    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.SetupLicensing.get_InstalledOfficeServersProduct()

Comment: That sounds like a plausible source. You probably deleted the wrong regkeys.if you did not take a backup of your regkeys, ou should look start looking for backups of the servers OS... Hope it wasnt a production environment...

Answer (score 0):

Some Troubleshooting worth trying:

1. Try checking options under "Upgrade and Migration" under central administration
2. "Enable Features on existing sites " Try this option under "Upgrade and Migration" in Central Administration
3. Run configuration wizard.

Comment: I ran Configuration wizard too. but i wont help me. When ever i try to create a new site collection. I got the same error. that I show you above.

Comment: please let me know if this work for me. the exact error message I am getting http://glorix.blogspot.com/2007/09/attempted-to-read-or-write-protected.html